# how to make more display only few lines at a time?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

On linux `more -10 <file>` displays only 10 lines at a time of file `file`. On a macOS Terminal, however, this does not work (for me).

How can I get this to work? Or how else can I get equivalent behaviour with `less`?

I should say that I run OSX 10.12.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`more -10` is a GNU extension, not standard.  `more -n 10` will work anywhere—whether with GNU `more` or BSD or any implementation of [POSIX `more`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/more.html).

**Use `more -n 10 filename`.**

Answer (score 4):

`less -10 <file>` on macOS 10.13 also scrolls forward 10 lines at a time.  The major difference is that it fills the first screen, as opposed to `more` which only generates the specified number of lines even on the first screen.

If that's not acceptable, the `LINES` env variable can override the number of lines on the screen.  So something like

`env LINES=10 less <file>`

will force 10 lines on the first screen, and also scrolls forward 10 lines at a time.

Comment: Okay, but I'm on OSX 10.12.5. `less -10 filename` does not work, but setting the environment variable `LINES` does. However, that is not quite what I want (because it sticks). Also, `less` output doesn't stay after the command is finished.

Answer (score 2):

You can type 'head -10 filename'
OR:

You can type `more filename` which will fill screen first time. After that type a number before hitting space to specify the number of lines on the 2nd scroll. You have to type a number each time to keep scrolling thru the file.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work for me. Also, I only want to see the first `n` lines.

Comment: @Walter You can use 'head -10 filename' to get only 1st 10 lines.

Comment: If you convert that comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Walter  I edited my answer to the answer you used. Thanks

Comment: Why the -10 on this answer??  The OP liked it and was going to give me credit!

Comment: The -10 may come from me accepting another answer, preferring it over yours. Sorry.

Comment: oh, that's ok. I thought I got that from a moderator for some reason.  Sorry about that.